# Eclipse Java application: Returning exit code \= 0 opens unwanted window

Tags: java, eclipse, exit-code

We're building an application in Java based on Eclipse. Its entry point implements `IApplication`. The exit code is set by method `start()`.

The problem is that if the exit code is not 0, Eclipse presents a dialog box saying "Java was started but returned exit code=...".  After the user closes the dialog, the application terminates and the exit code is correctly set.

How can I prevent the warning dialog from being displayed?

Thanks, Ulrich

> Windows 8.1
>
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

Comment: How do you exit your application?

Comment: just by letting the start() method return. The return value then is the exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this:

--launcher.suppressErrors

to your eclipse.ini file, it should prevent the dialog to be shown.

If you don't want the message to appear on your stderr as well, you should set the system variable "eclipse.exitdata" to empty. That will prevent any message to be written, either on stderr or on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your IApplication.start(IApplicationContext) method before returning your exit code:

```
// prevent launcher messages
System.setProperty(IApplicationContext.EXIT_DATA_PROPERTY, "");
return exitCode;
```

And add `--launcher.suppressErrors` to the command you run.

Linking the useful bug on that topic: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=313819